# Java regular expression finding special char in non-comments

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, replace

after I switched workspace encoding to UTF-8 and back (Windows-ISO), all my (German) umlauts got converted to ï¿½.

I want to replace all the ï¿½ by Eclipse Find/Replace with static references.

```
public interface StringConstants {
    public static final String ae = "\u00E4";
    public static final String oe = "\u00F6";
    public static final String ue = "\u00FC";
    public static final String AE = "\u00C4";
    public static final String OE = "\u00D6";
    public static final String UE = "\u00DC";
    public static final String ss = "\u00DF";
}
```

I don't want to replace all the Comments, because nobody cares about them...

Up till now I could do that with

```
Find: ^[^//](.*?)(ï¿½)+

Replacement: $1" + StringConstants.ue + "
```

It would omit CVS comments

```
// ï¿½ber
```

But it doesn't work for comments with blanks or code in front of them and blockcomments.
e.g.:

```
doSomething(); // blabla ï¿½ber // <-- should be omitted
/** 
 * ï¿½ber // <-- should be omitted
 */
\t// ï¿½ber // <-- should be omitted
log.debug("ï¿½ber"); // <-- should be replaced
```

i tried to write a regex which should omit // comments with any characters before, but it didn't work.

(background: There is no defined Charset in any documentation for that code, not even in the VCS. I am the last developer for this tool, all other developers are gone. The code is developed under windows for an tomcat on Linux - AppUsers have Windows too)

Can someone help me?

Cheers, 
Martin

Comment: I guess you do not want comments to be converted for the version control system. Nevertheless consider still doing that, to maintain code reading quality (=not misleading readers, that something is wrong with the encoding). And write a file scanning tool, to identify all non 7-bits ASCII text. One would definitely feel safer. P.S. UTF-8 is a good solid choice.

Comment: Assuming that you still have original source files, why don't you simply open them in something like `Notepad++` and save as `UTF-8 without BOM`? You will only need to do it once, and all your German umlauts should be still intact.

Comment: IMHO, you should replace the german chars in the comments too. I don't know about the others, but *I do care about comments* `;)`. You won't need such a hard regexp then.

Comment: Once I change to UTF-8 I'm getting compilation warnings:  `warning: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8 //?ber`. @mvp: If it was so easy... I have got 1800+ classes with some of them 1000+ LOC (some are 3000+ LOC) to resave. With the replace thing I have to remake only 5 classes (grep has shown me the special char only there).

Comment: Eclipse converted now all my Umlauts from the project to � with UTF-8 enabled... :/ When compiling project with UTF-8 some JavaScript functions stopped working (e.g.: <button onclick=".." value="hinzfügen"). BTW: I prefer UTF-8 too, that's why I changed my workspace Encoding in first place.

Comment: With so many files, you could use `iconv` to batch convert your files to UTF-8. If your conversion is done properly - correct `from` encoding, your converted result should not cause `unmappable character for encoding` errors.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
^(?:(?!//|(?:\*\s)).)*(ï¿½)+.*
```

here you need to replace gourp 1 (the only group) with the text you want.
The regex searches for lines with "ï¿½" not preceded by '//' or '*\s'